# USB application send serial to text

Tags: c#

good morning.
I am trying to make an application that uses a USB port for serial data resection (ascii) and can write to text in any note, as would a Terminal, keyboard or scanner.
The question is does anyone have an idea where to start?

Comment: The `keybd_event` function allows a user program to pretend that keyboard actions occur.  You can find [a p/invoke declaration allowing you to call it from C#](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/keybd_event.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using WindowsInput.Native;
using WindowsInput;
namespace Consola_cs
{
    class Program
       
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            

        // Tamaño ventana consola.
        Console.WindowWidth = 55; // X. Ancho.
            Console.WindowHeight = 18; // Y. Alto.

            // Cree un nuevo objeto SerialPort con la configuración predeterminada.
            SerialPort Puerto_serie = new SerialPort("COM4");

            Puerto_serie.BaudRate = 9600;
            Puerto_serie.Parity = Parity.None;
            Puerto_serie.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            Puerto_serie.DataBits = 8;
            Puerto_serie.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            Puerto_serie.RtsEnable = true;

            // Establecer los tiempos de espera de lectura / escritura.
            Puerto_serie.ReadTimeout = 500; // Milisegundos.
            Puerto_serie.WriteTimeout = 500;

            // Detecta cualquier dato recibido.
            Puerto_serie.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

            Puerto_serie.Open(); // Abrir puerto.

            ConsoleKey tecla;
            Console.WriteLine("Pulse tecla Escape para apagar:");

            do
            {
                tecla = Console.ReadKey(true).Key; // Espera pulsación de teclas.
            }
            while (tecla != ConsoleKey.Escape); // Pulsa Escape para salir del menú.

            Console.WriteLine("Presione cualquier tecla para terminar...");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadKey(); // Espera pulsar una tecla cualquiera.
            Puerto_serie.Close(); // Cierra el puerto serie.
        }
        private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string entradaDatos = sp.ReadExisting(); // Almacena los datos recibidos en la variable tipo string.
            Console.WriteLine("Dato recibido:" + entradaDatos); // Muestra en pantalla los datos recibidos.
            InputSimulator Simulator = new InputSimulator(); // Utiliza la libreria using WindowsInput.
            Simulator.Keyboard.TextEntry(entradaDatos); //Muestra el text donde se encunetra el cursor los datos recibidos.
        }
       
    }
}
```